# how to convert a dataframe to a custom collection

Tags: python, arrays, list, dataframe, collections

How to convert each row of a dataframe to a list without , among the elements!

I have a dataframe and need to convert it to a collection such as the following:

```
[[1 2]
[3 6]
...
[0 9]
]
```

the dataframe looks like the following:

```
1 2
3 6
...
0 9
```

### How can I do that?

In fact, I have the following code and when I run it, I get the following code:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

 

boston = load_boston()

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split( Xtrain, Ytrain, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

xgbr = xgb.XGBRegressor(verbosity=0)
xgbr.fit(x_train, y_train)
score = xgbr.score(x_train, y_train)   

print("Training score: ", score)
```

---

### error:

```
-
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-b66a01011827> in <module>
     13 
     14 xgbr = xgb.XGBRegressor(verbosity=0)
---> 15 xgbr.fit(x_train, y_train)
     16 score = xgbr.score(x_train, y_train)
     17 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
    420         for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args):
    421             kwargs[k] = arg
--> 422         return f(**kwargs)
    423 
    424     return inner_f

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, base_margin, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, xgb_model, sample_weight_eval_set, feature_weights, callbacks)
    567         self.n_features_in_ = X.shape[1]
    568 
--> 569         train_dmatrix = DMatrix(data=X, label=y, weight=sample_weight,
    570                                 base_margin=base_margin,
    571                                 missing=self.missing,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in __init__(self, data, label, weight, base_margin, missing, silent, feature_names, feature_types, nthread, enable_categorical)
    507         self.handle = handle
    508 
--> 509         self.set_info(label=label, weight=weight, base_margin=base_margin)
    510 
    511         self.feature_names = feature_names

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
    420         for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args):
    421             kwargs[k] = arg
--> 422         return f(**kwargs)
    423 
    424     return inner_f

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in set_info(self, label, weight, base_margin, group, label_lower_bound, label_upper_bound, feature_names, feature_types, feature_weights)
    528         '''Set meta info for DMatrix.'''
    529         if label is not None:
--> 530             self.set_label(label)
    531         if weight is not None:
    532             self.set_weight(weight)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in set_label(self, label)
    657         """
    658         from .data import dispatch_meta_backend
--> 659         dispatch_meta_backend(self, label, 'label', 'float')
    660 
    661     def set_weight(self, weight):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/data.py in dispatch_meta_backend(matrix, data, name, dtype)
    654     '''Dispatch for meta info.'''
    655     handle = matrix.handle
--> 656     _validate_meta_shape(data)
    657     if data is None:
    658         return

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/data.py in _validate_meta_shape(data)
    584 def _validate_meta_shape(data):
    585     if hasattr(data, 'shape'):
--> 586         assert len(data.shape) == 1 or (
    587             len(data.shape) == 2 and
    588             (data.shape[1] == 0 or data.shape[1] == 1))

AssertionError:
```

Comment: how does your df looks like?

Comment: without brackets and each one in a separate row

Comment: can you edit you question and show exactly how your dataframe looks like

Comment: I updated the question, please look at it

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have , in between elements of list.
There is a built in method which would be the fastest method also, calling `tolist` on the `.values` np array:

try

```
df.values.tolist()
```

example: if DF is

```
admit   gpa  gre  rank   
0  3.61  380     3  
1  3.67  660     3  
1  3.19  640     4  
0  2.93  520     4
```

this output will be

```
[[0.0, 3.61, 380.0, 3.0],
[1.0, 3.67, 660.0, 3.0],
[1.0, 3.19, 640.0, 4.0],
[0.0, 2.93, 520.0, 4.0]]
```

Comment: my desire output does not have comma between values!!!

Comment: so you are saying [1  2] should be first element of your list but `[1 2]` in python is not a valid list which will raise an error it must be `[1,2]` or `['1 2']` where '1 2' becomes a string